# How not to use UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in Filter Chain?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I am working on a spring boot app where I am adding a custom filter and adding method addFilterBefore.

This is my config configure method:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(btoBSecurityFilter,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.httpBasic();
    }
```

Here's my Custom Filter:

```
@Component
public class BtoBSecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
       //I dont want to use this as I dont want to use UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.  
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(getAuthentication(7312L,"tokenlelo"));
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);
        logger.info("hey aaya");
    }

    // dont want to use this.
    public Authentication getAuthentication(Long userId, String token) {
        UserDetails userDetails = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                .withUsername("")
                .password("")
                .build();
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("", "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }

}
```

Now the above code works but I dont want the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to happen in my case and I just want my customFilter to filter out requests for me.

How can I do this? I am not able to use `addFilter` method as it gives order errors.
I just want my custom filter to run and dont want SecurityContext to set or save anything.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: how do you authenticate your users and what is the purpose of your custom filter?

Comment: Double posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73372531/filter-does-not-have-a-registered-order-and-cannot-be-added-without-a-specified

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` doesn't guarantee that `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` will filter your request.

If you look at source code (using your IDEA or github), especially at [`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java) method `boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`, and at [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java) constructors, you'll see that `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` only filters requests which match the authentication request (default is POST-request to "/login").

As you set your custom filter before `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, this filter will be invoked anyway after your custom filter, unless you skip `filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse)` method in your custom filter code.
But, as I said before, it doesn't mean `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` will filter your request.

So, it doesn't depend on using `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` is just one of the implementations of the `Authentication`, which can be used in your case. When you use public constructor of this class with a collection of `GrantedAuthority`, your create a trusted (i.e. isAuthenticated() = true) authentication token. So security context will know that request is already authenticated.

By the way, constructor you use is intended to be called only by  `AuthenticationManager` or `AuthenticationProvider` - that is stated in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.util.Collection)).
For safe usage try [static factory method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html#authenticated(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.util.Collection)):

```
return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(principal, credentials, userDetails.getAuthorities());
```